# Printing starting number for Collatz Conjecture in C

Tags: c

I have been working on this school assignment and we are working on creating the [Collatz Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) in C. I have completed all of the code and the only thing left is to have the number passed in also print with the numbers I get back from my logic. I tried using a `printf()` before and after each time the input is changed but this only prints the number twice for each iteration. Below is an example of how it should work. I will also put my code down below.

`For example`:
If I pass in the number `4`. I should get back `4,2,1`

`Input Passed :` `./hw1 4`

`Expected Output: 4 , 2, 1
                 Child ID is : 0
                Child ID 1 is : 17488
                Parent ID is 17487
                Parent PID 1 is : 17488`

`Actual Output: , 2, 1
              Child ID is : 0
              Child ID 1 is : 17488
              Parent ID is 17487
              Parent PID 1 is : 17488`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  // this is the number the user passes in 
  int n;

  int pid;
  int my_status;
  pid_t my_pid, my_secondpid;
  my_pid = fork();

  if (argc == 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./hw1 <starting value>\n");

    return -1;
  }

  n = atoi(argv[1]); //  n is the input starting value

  // Error checking

  if (n < 0 || n == 0) {
    printf("Number cannot be less than 0");
    return 1;

  }

  //pid_t my_pid = fork();

  if (my_pid < 0) {
    printf("Unsuccesfull in creating the child process");
    return 1;

  } else if (my_pid == 0) {

    my_secondpid = getpid();

    //pid_t my_child = getpid();

    while (n != 1) {
      //pid_t my_child = getpid();

      // if the number is even
      if (n % 2 == 0) {
        //printf("%d " , n);
        n = n / 2;
        printf(" , %d", n);
        // printf("\n child id is : %d", my_child);
        // printf(" \n parent : %d" , my_pid);
        //printf("\n parent id is : %d" , my_pid);

      }
      // if the number is odd
      else if (n % 2 != 0) {
        //printf("%d" , n);
        n = 3 * n + 1;
        printf(" ,  %d", n);
        //printf("\n child id is : %d", my_child); 
        // printf(" \n parent : %d" , my_pid);
        //printf("\n parent id is : %d" , my_pid);

      }
      //printf("%d \n", n);

    } // end of while
    printf("\n");
    printf("\nChild ID is : %d", my_pid);
    printf("\nChild ID 1 is : %d", my_secondpid);
    //printf("\nProcess ID : %d", pid); 
  } // end of else if

  else {
    wait(NULL);
    my_secondpid = getpid();
    //printf("\n The starting  pid is : %d \n" , my_pid);
    printf("\nParent ID is %d", my_secondpid);
    printf("\nParent PID 1 is : %d", my_pid);
    printf("\n");

  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `pid_t` is not certainly matched with `"%d"`.  Suggest a cast as in `printf("%ld", (long) my_secondpid);`

Comment: thanks I will fix this also. Any ideas on my original problem? @chux

Comment: Step 1, post _exact_ input used, output seen and expected.

Comment: OK check post now @chux.

Comment: Why expect `4` given `n = n / 2;
        printf(" , %d", n);` divides before printing?

Comment: Unless I am missing something, what's wrong with printing it before the `while` loop?

Comment: I got it. I added `printf(" %d" , n);` before the while loop.

Comment: thanks also @user58697

Comment: You can improve the efficiency by replacing `n % 2 == 0` with `n & 1 == 0` and removing `if (n % 2 != 0)` entirely leaving `else` alone. (if it is not *even* then it is *odd* and there is no need for the second conditional)

Comment: @DavidCRankin There is no need to break out the `&`; `n % 2` is more readable and any compiler with any sort of optimization will notice `2` is a compile-time constant and a power of 2 and do that for you. I agree the second `if` should be removed.

Comment: You also need some type of overflow check as values using `uint64_t` will overflow during iteration of the sequence. E.g the wikipedia example for a start of `7,579,309,213,675,935`. For the odd case, e.g. `uint64_t tmp = 3 * val; if (tmp / 3 != val || tmp == UINT64_MAX) { /* overflow */ }`

Comment: I'm puzzled that the code is using `fork()` at all; it really isn't necessary to print the Collatz sequence.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `n & 1 == 0` fails on those rusting 1s' complement machines when `n < 0`.  (which should not happen given `if (n < 0`). . I expect `unsigned n` instead of `int` for this code anyways.

Comment: Prior to `n = 3 * n + 1;`, code can use `if (n > (INT_MAX - 1)/3) Handle_Overflow();` to detect when `n` is too big.

Comment: @DanielH, I'm a little confused. `n % 2 == 0` more readable than `n & 1 == 0`? That's a close call. Now the concern about the rusting one-compliments machines not handling `n & 1 == 0` correctly is the larger concern. One day the againg capacitors will hopefully remedy that.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `n & 1 == 0` is equivalent to `n & 0` is equivalent to `0`. It's just broken.

Comment: No, take two examples. `3` (e.g. `11 & 1 == 1`) and `4` (`100 & 1 = 0`) it is the same odd/even test for all positive numbers (and two-compliment negative numbers) that avoids the division overhead by using AND. If the `ones-bit` is set (e.g. the number is odd) it tests `true` otherwise `false`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin In general, `%` for "is divisible by" is more understandable than bit-fiddling. What if the Collatz conjecture were defined differently for numbers divisible by 3? Parallel use case, parallel structure. As for `n & 1 == 0` being broken, look at the [operator precedence rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). Since `&` binds less tightly than `==`, `n & 1 == 0` is equivalent to `n & (1 == 0)`, not `(n & 1) == 0` as you'd expect.

Comment: I see the argument, but if you think like a computer, or have any background in assembly, `n & 1` is equivalent or more clear than a modulo. Why? odd/even is simply the result of the question "Is the ones-bit set?" (for all but the rusting ones-compliment negative representations - which thankfully I have yet to encounter in 32 years of computing -- unless the old Amdols or Univac systems used for the BaseIC for the Shuttle simulators were... but I digress) While modern CPU division handling has largely removed the division penalty, which one is more readable depends on how you think.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `11 & 1 == 1` is `11 & 1` is `1`. `100 & 1 == 0` is `100 & 0` is `0`.

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("Number cannot be less than 0");` and similar statements:  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  Suggest using:  `fprintf( stderr, "your error message]n" );` and when the error indication is from a c library function Suggest using: `perror( "your error message" );` as that outputs to `stderr`, both your error message AND the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.

Comment: OT: regarding: `fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./hw1 <starting value>\n");`  The name of the executable can be changed at any time.  Suggest using: `fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <starting value>\n", argv[0] );`

Comment: @melpomene I'm not sure where the misunderstanding is, but this complete example should explain, `#include <stdio.h> int main (void) {for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) if (((i & 1) == 0) != ((i % 2) == 0)) fprintf (stderr, "error: %d\n", i); }` There will be no output.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin You changed the code. `i & 1 == 0` is not the same as `(i & 1) == 0`.